# Переменные с одинаковым значением не равны

Tags: php

Данный код:

```
$row_price = (float)$query->row['price'];
var_dump($row_price);
echo '<br>';
$price = (float)$price;
var_dump($price);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($row_price == $price);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($row_price === $price);
```

Выводит следующее:

```
float(361.7625)
float(361.7625)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Внимание вопрос: как переменные с одинаковым значением могут быть не равны?
Я что то не знаю или не понимаю?

Comment: `var_dump($row_price - $price);`

Comment: @Igor, `float(-5.6843418860808E-14)`

Comment: Вот Вам и ответ.

Comment: @Igor, а можете объяснить, почему так происходит, как округлить или что сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этих переменных - разные числа. При стандартном выводе (преобразовании в строку) с семью значащими цифрами - строки получаются одинаковыми. Но проверка строгого равенства учитывает разницу в любых соответствующих битах.

Замените

```
var_dump($row_price === $price);
```

на

```
var_dump(abs($row_price - $price) < 1.0e-8);
```

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: но для меня самое простое будет преобразовывать эти числа в строки и сравнивать: `(string)$row_price === (string)$price`

Comment: преобразование в строку - операция гораздо более медленная, @Aleksar